# How to change the way FreshMvvm expects the page name for an entity?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, freshmvvm

I have a simple project built on FreshMvvm and there is only one entity, `Contact` with 2 string properties, `Name` and `Number`.

The application shows a list of contacts and when a user taps on a contact, it opens the `ContactPage.xaml` with the contact details.

The application works ok, but I would like to change the name of `ContactPage.xaml`, to `ContactDetailsPage.xaml` and in this case when FreshMvvm tries to find `ContactPage.xaml` upon opening contact details, it fails.

How can I tell to FreshMvvm to seek for `ContactDetailsPage.xaml` instead of `ContactPage.xaml` ?

ContactListPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FreshMvvmDemo.Pages.ContactListPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Number}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ContactPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FreshMvvmDemo.Pages.ContactPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Contact.Name}"></Entry>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Contact.Number}"></Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: How did you tell FreshMvvm  to find ContactPage.xaml before you change the name?

Comment: I did not tell anything special, it is automatic behaviour as I understand. I suppose FreshMvvm just extracts class name from the `ContactListPageModel` name and constructs name `ContactPage.xaml` for one selected item. Are my assumptions incorrect?

Comment: I just check the sample and document of FreshMvvm, it says `A Page must have a corresponding PageModel`, I guess you have a `ContactPageModel` in your project. If you want to change the page name to `ContactDetailsPage`, you should change the model name to `ContactDetailPageModel` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open `ContactDetailsPage.xaml` instead of `ContactPage.xaml` I have to rename corresponding ViewModel class from `ContactPageModel` to `ContactDetailsPageModel`.

Thanks @JackHua-MSFT for help.